# Microsoft Point of Service - PosPrinter TransactionPrint error handling

Tags: c#, printing, opos

I am dealing with a C# application that automatically prints food and drink orders to an Epson printer after the items have been requested via an order terminal.

The printer is ethernet and is setup on the terminal in the EPSON OPOS ADK Version2.68E driver interface.

The code is using the 'Microsoft.PointOfService.PosPrinter' class to interact with the printer.

The printing logic is wrapped up in a transaction using the PosPrinter 'TransactionPrint' instance method.

There is logic which catches any exceptions thrown by the TransactionPrint method and if an exception is thrown it is assumed that the print did not work. However, this is not always the case e.g. if the network cable is unplugged from the printer before the TransactionPrint method call returns the ticket completes printing but an exception is thrown in the code, therefore a duplicate ticket is produced when the code retries the print.

Does anyone know of a way to tell if the print succeeded even though a network exception has been raised? I've looked through all the properties on the 'PosPrinter' object but can't see anything that will help. I need a way to determine if the print worked and then flag the order as having been printed in order to avoid duplicate tickets.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible.   If the library knew that the printer successfully printed a slip, I wouldn't expect it to throw an exception in the first place.  You might have to try another approach, such as considering the rare duplicated slip or, if there's a user available, you might ask the user if they want to try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sam. Yes, it's not looking likely. I've never tried async OPOS printing - perhaps it can supply progress of the printing... It's a difficult one because the application is designed to run in the background as a tray app and is supposed to be automatic as possible.